# How to alter WM_CLASS value in a Java GUI application based on Swing or NetBeans Platform?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, xorg

All Swing/NetBeans-based Java GUI applications seem to have the same `WM_CLASS` value:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", "java-lang-Thread"
```

This parameter can be viewed by issuing `xprop` command and pointing to the window. The practical purpose of customizing it is to let Mac-like docks (AWN, for example (and, perhaps, Ubuntu's Unity)) distinguish the application windows and group them under the application's pinned launcher icon. For this to work `StartupWMClass` parameter is to be set accordingly in the `.application` file in `~/.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications`. Needless to say, AWN (and analogues) get confused in case more than one application uses the same string for `WM_CLASS`.

Comment: See also [bug ID: 6528430](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6528430).

Comment: Looks like they don't intend to hurry with this... :-( I hope modern window management systems of Gnome 3, Unity and, perhaps, Windows 7 will cause Oracle to wake up. Sadly, seems that they've chosen a different, Unity-specific way to integrate with Unity.

Comment: By the way, "Bug ID: 6528430" seems to be a Java 6 issue. Why not to file the same for Java 7 and 8? I doubt they will ever add such a feature to a legacy Java version, the chance seems much better with in-development bleeding-edge like Java 8.

Comment: And yes, does anybody know how to comment and vote there? The page seems pretty static: I can see some comments, but I can't find how to post mine nor even how to log-in.

Comment: Does this help: http://elliotth.blogspot.it/2007/02/fixing-wmclass-for-your-java.html ?

For the applications you can't change the code, you can also check this WM Agent https://github.com/jelmerk/window-matching-agent
With that, you only have to edit the application command line.

Answer (score 4):

[This blog post](http://elliotth.blogspot.it/2007/02/fixing-wmclass-for-your-java.html) found the field in [`Toolkit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) that controls it, named `awtAppClassName`. It suggests using reflection to modify it:

```
Toolkit xToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
java.lang.reflect.Field awtAppClassNameField = xToolkit.getClass().getDeclaredField("awtAppClassName");
awtAppClassNameField.setAccessible(true);
awtAppClassNameField.set(xToolkit, applicationName);
```